# use sed to replace string with regular expression line by line

Tags: regex, command-line, sed

I tried to do some operation on a clex file, the format is like:

```
name:{id:xxx, ... ...} alias: aaa;
name:{id:yyy, ... ...} alias: bbb;
name:{id:zzz, ... ...} alias: ccc;
```

What I need to do is to replace the content after name with the ones afer alias. so the result should be:

```
name:{id:aaa, ... ...} alias: aaa;
name:{id:bbb, ... ...} alias: bbb;
name:{id:ccc, ... ...} alias: ccc;
```

Can I use sed to complete the operation? I tried to use regular expression but failed.
Then I tried to use for loop:

```
readarray lines < "$file"

for line in "${lines[@]}"; 
do
    ???
done
```

But was struggled about how to do the replace thing. Can anyone help with this please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try this line:

```
sed -r 's/(name:\{id:)[^,]*(.*alias: )([^;]*);/\1\3\2\3;/' file
```

with your example data:

```
kent$  echo "name:{id:xxx, ... ...} alias: aaa;
name:{id:yyy, ... ...} alias: bbb;
name:{id:zzz, ... ...} alias: ccc;"|sed -r 's/(name:\{id:)[^,]*(.*alias: )([^;]*);/\1\3\2\3;/'
name:{id:aaa, ... ...} alias: aaa;
name:{id:bbb, ... ...} alias: bbb;
name:{id:ccc, ... ...} alias: ccc;
```

Comment: Thank you for that, but what's the meaning of " \1\3\2\3 " ? does this mean the column?

Comment: they mean groups. those `(...)`s

Comment: oh I realize now. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can use sed with something like this:

```
s/(name:\{id:)[^,]*,(.*)(alias: )([^;]*)/\1\4,\2\3\4/g
```

Answer (score 0):

`sed 's/name:{id:[a-z],+(.*)alias: ([a_z]+)/name:{id:\2,\1/alias: \1/`

I give you that untested, some control chars might need to be escaped. You can tune the `[a-z]+` to match your alias matching.